# jQuery/Sizzle selector to find current element's parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

**Is there a way I can get the selected element's parent using only jQuery's/sizzle's CSS selectors?**

I need to be able to get an element's parent while using jQuery, but I'm **unable** use `jQuery('#myelement').parent()` since I'm receiving the selector as a string and the "user" needs to be able to move back up the tree.

I can't see anything in the docs, so I'm wondering whether it's undocumented or if there's a hack I can use?

Comment: why are you unable to use .parent() ?

Comment: he might need the parent for the live function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSS can't traverse back up the tree like XPath can, I'm doing a bit of munging and checking for the character `<` in the string, splitting on that and calling `.parent()` manually. Its not optimal but it's working.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution (ie. the one which actually use jQuery *selectors* rather than jQuery API) is this one :

```
$(':has(> #myElement)');
```

That means that your "current element" actually has to be the 'has' parameter rather than the base expression. It shouldn't change anything, except that it is a bit less readable than `<`.

For reference, the jQuery API may not be a valid replacement to selectors in a few cases, such as :

```
$(document).on('click', ':has(> .widget)', function () {
    // ...
});
```

In this case, the selector allows to filter the live events.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(jQuery('#myelement').parent())` is getting the object without the additional function.

Ok, end of jokes ;)

I'm guessing that You need the parent selected for the live function and that is why You can't get it this way.

```
jQuery('#'+jQuery('#myelement').parent().attr('id')).live(something);
```

It's the way You do it to make it work.
If the parent element has no id You can use more complicated tricks

```
    //newline for reading comfort. skip it. --v
jQuery('[title='+jQuery('#myelement').parent() 
.attr('title',Math.round(Math.random()*100000)+']').attr('title')).live(something);
```

You can use id or title or class, depends on what is already on the page

And if You **really** need it to be found by just css selector - as far as I know this is impossible with css selectors by design

Comment: It *really* needs to be done via a CSS selector as the selector is being passed in as a string. Its rather annoying that CSS can't traverse back up the tree like XPath can. :(

Answer (score 0):

Such selector doesn't exists, nor in CSS neither in jQuery/Sizzle.

You can change the source code?

If yes, it is possible to add custom pseudo-selector:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].getParent = function (node, index, prop, nodes) {
    return jQuery(node).parent(); 
};
```

Use example (Note that parent already exists, so I've used getParent instead):

```
jQuery('#myelement:getParent');
```

Comment: As @maël-nison's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24571489/1273938) show, it is indeed possible to select a parent directly.

Comment: This does not work (anymore?). Pseudo-selectors are just filters, they can't return another element. You can see here that `h1:getParent` returns the same element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMZYQ.png